# Selenium basic opening a url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am just starting with selenium.

I made a simple python script that should open a url and print the price of a product there.

Here it is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/bin/phantomjs')
url = 'http://www.stance.com/shop/product/paint-trap'
print "Driver Made"
driver.get(url)
print "URL got"
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="h1--title-price"]/span[2]').text
print price
driver.close()
```

But, it just prints: "Driver Made" and never prints "URL got" nor the price.

It seems to be getting stuck on the driver.get(url), but I don't know why.

I would like to know how to print the price and how to stop driver.get(url) from running eternally.

If I interrupt it with a ctrl C, i get:

```
Driver Made
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver.get(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 213, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 199, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 463, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: you are priniting it ->  7 line -> print "URL got"

Comment: "URL got" is never printing, because get(url) runs eternally. I want to know why get(url) is running eternally and how to stop it. @ShubhamJain

Comment: `$14.00` is the result i got.The code is working correctly i guess

Comment: weird, thanks for running it @vks are you also using phantomjs?

Comment: @Rorschach no `firefox` .... check if `phantom` is supported

Comment: A little tricky to debug without a little more information (perhaps the error message?). I would triple check your `executable_path` leads exactly to the `phantomjs.exe` file, use `driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.jpg')` to check that the url is loading correctly - sometimes the size of the browser being used can cause issues in PhantomJS

Comment: Maybe reinstalling PhantomJS can help you out?

Comment: I will try that @Maikflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code prints- (in windows).

```
Driver Made
URL got
$14.00
```

Working code as below

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Desktop\phantomjs.exe")

driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
url = 'http://www.stance.com/shop/product/paint-trap'
print "Driver Made"
driver.get(url)
print "URL got"
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//*[@id='h1--title-price']/span)[2]")
for i in price:
    print i.text
driver.close()
```

**N.B. Make sure phantom executable path and selenium library is correct in other oses.**

Comment: Sadly, mine still runs eternally with this. It must be some error that doesn't have to do with the code, I am gonna try reinstalling phantomJS and if that doesn't work I'll try firefox

Comment: Thank you for affirming that the code works, I will mark your answer as correct, since the code works and that is what I was asking for. I think my ubuntu was just running extraordinarily slow. So, I will go about fixing that.